# Does/will pact.io provide support for testNG test framework?

Tags: pact

I can see from documentation that pact.io tool can integrate well with junit4 and junit5 to execute tests.

- https://docs.pact.io/implementation_guides/jvm/readme
- https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-jvm/tree/master/consumer

Are there any plans to support testNG too?

Answer (score 0):

There are no current plans that I'm aware of.

I would suggest raising a feature request in our public [roadmap](https://pact.canny.io/) to raise awareness and see if any of the maintainers/community are willing to contribute.

Of course, you are free to create a project that supports testng and I'm sure we could find a home to link to it in our documentation for others who use the framework.